# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [rows, columns]

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, compiler-errors

i dont know what to do. I want to print out the classifier score but its not working. Can someone Help me?  I really dont know what is the Problem maybe its something with the Numpy Array (numpy.arrange).

```
import pandas as pd

from matplotlib import colors
from matplotlib import pyplot

import numpy as np

from sklearn import neighbors
from sklearn.svm import SVC

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

gesundeMenschen = pd.read_csv('data/control_file.csv', sep=',', header=None)
gesundeMenschen.columns= [np.arange(10000)]
krankeMenschen = pd.read_csv('data/patient_file.csv', sep=',', header=None)
krankeMenschen.columns= [np.arange(10000)]

gesundeMenschen.loc[7] = 0
krankeMenschen.loc[7] = 1

xG = gesundeMenschen.loc[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]]
yG = gesundeMenschen.loc[7]

xK = krankeMenschen.loc[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]]
yK = krankeMenschen.loc[7]

xG_train,xG_test,yG_train,yG_test = train_test_split(xG,yG,test_size=0.33)

cls = SVC()
cls.fit(xG_train,yG_train)

print(cls.score(xG_test,yG_test))
```

Comment: What's the error or the problem? What is your result and what is your expected result?

Comment: I´m getting this error "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [7, 10000]" i want an Output in the console "cls.score()"

Comment: Please add the full traceback. That might make it clearer to me.

Comment: Question of the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62810487/error-found-input-variables-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-rows-column

Answer (score 0):

File "C:/Users//main.py", line 27, in 
xG_train,xG_test,yG_train,yG_test = train_test_split(xG,yG,test_size=0.33)
File "C:\Users\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_split.py", line 2127, in train_test_split
arrays = indexable(*arrays)
File "C:\Users\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 293, in indexable
check_consistent_length(*result)
File "C:\Users\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 256, in check_consistent_length
raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [7, 10000]